# Perl Sys::Syslog on Solaris

Tags: perl, solaris, syslog

Has anyone got [Sys::Syslog](http://perldoc.perl.org/Sys/Syslog.html) to work on Solaris?  (I'm running Sys::Syslog 0.05 on Perl v5.8.4 on SunOS 5.10 on SPARC).  Here's what doesn't work for me:

```
openlog "myprog", "pid", "user" or die;
syslog "crit", "%s", "Test from $0" or die;
closelog() or warn "Can't close: $!";
system "tail /var/adm/messages";
```

Whatever I do, the closelog returns an error and nothing ever gets logged anywhere.

Comment: It would be rather helpful if you included the error here.

Answer (score 3):

By default, Sys::Syslog is going to try to connect with one of the following socket types:

```
[ 'tcp', 'udp', 'unix', 'stream' ]
```

On Solaris, though, you'll need to use an inet socket.  Call:

```
setlogsock('inet', $hostname);
```

and things should start working.

Answer (score 1):

In general you can answer "does module $x work on platform $y" questions by looking at the CPAN testers matrix, [like here](http://bbbike.radzeit.de/~slaven/cpantestersmatrix.cgi?dist=Sys-Syslog+0.26).

Answer (score 0):

setlogsock('inet') didn't do it for me (it looks for host "syslog") but building and installing Sys::Syslog from CPAN did.  The Sys::Syslog that comes with Solaris 10 is ancient.